# Why an inherited interface can't be converted to its base interface in generic context?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement an interface inheritance system in my C# project, but I can't get it to work.

Here is a simplified version:

```cs
public interface BaseInterface {}

public abstract class AbstractClass<T> where T : BaseInterface {}

public interface ChildInterface : BaseInterface {}

public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass<ChildInterface> {}
```

I want to use it as follow:

```cs
AbstractClass<BaseInterface> c = new ConcreteClass();
```

The last line of code gives me the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConcreteClass' to 'AbstractClass<BaseInterface>'

Why is the conversion impossible?

Comment: Does the issue occur **only** if `AbstractClass` has generics involved? What might that tell you?

Comment: `AbstractClass` is invariant, and you want a covariant type. See [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) in generics. You're limited to interfaces for co/contravariance, so you aren't going to be able to do what you want with an abstract class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't able to make the assignment because the base class, `AbstractClass<T>`, is invariant. What you want to be able to make that kind of assignment is a covariant type. Defining Covariance and Contravariance is limited to interfaces, so that means we need another interface.

```
public interface IAbstractClass<out T> where T : BaseInterface { }  
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> : IAbstractClass<T> where T : BaseInterface { }
```

The `out` keyword marks the generic type parameter as covariant. We then implement that interface in `AbstractClass<T>`, and our other types can work expected through the interface. These are also the only alterations we need to make, we leave the other type definitions the same:

```
public interface BaseInterface { }
public interface ChildInterface : BaseInterface { }

public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass<ChildInterface> { }
```

We now have a covariant interface that `AbstractClass<T>` implements, and you can do the kind of assignment you desire, but you'll have to target the `IAbstractClass` interface.

```
public void Main() {
    IAbstractClass<BaseInterface> c = new ConcreteClass();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Let's have a play with your types and call them something different.

```
public interface IFruit { }

public abstract class BowlOf<Fruit> where Fruit : IFruit
{
    public void Add(Fruit fruit) { }
}

public class Apple : IFruit { }

public class BowlOfApples : BowlOf<Apple> { }
```

Now, with that - which is pretty much just a rename of the types (but changing `public interface ChildInterface : BaseInterface {}` to `public class Apple : IFruit { }`) then we create the following issue.

Let's say I have `public class Banana : IFruit { }` also and let's assume that the following is legal:

```
BowlOf<IFruit> c = new BowlOfApples();
```

Then I am perfectly fine to call `c.Add(new Banana())`. What!?! **You can't add a banana to a bowl of apples.**

And that's why the compiler is complaining when you try to do `AbstractClass<BaseInterface> c = new ConcreteClass();`.