# Why casting with generic types does not work?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, types

Hy all,
So I just want to work with generic and casting. But for some reason is does not work and I do not know why.

```
abstract class BaseModel {}

    class NewModel : BaseModel {}

    class BaseRepo<T> where T : BaseModel {}

    class NewRepo : BaseRepo<NewModel> {}

    class Test
    {
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            BaseRepo<BaseModel> t1 = new BaseRepo<BaseModel>();
            BaseRepo<NewModel> t2 = new NewRepo();
            BaseRepo<BaseModel> t3 = new BaseRepo<NewModel>();
            // Cannot convert initializer type 'TestGeneric.BaseRepo<TestGeneric.NewModel> to target type 'TestGeneric.BaseRepo<BaseModel>'.
            // Cannot implicitly convert type 'TestGeneric.BaseRepo<TestGeneric.NewModel>' to 'TestGeneric.BaseRepo<TestGeneric.BaseModel>'.
            // Type 'NewModel' doesn't match expected type 'BaseModel'.
            // Cannot convert source type 'TestGeneric.BaseRepo<TestGeneric.NewModel>' to target type 'TestGeneric.BaseRepo<TestGeneric.BaseModel>'.

            BaseRepo<BaseModel> t4 = new NewRepo();
            // Cannot convert initializer type 'TestGeneric.BaseRepo<TestGeneric.NewModel> to target type 'TestGeneric.BaseRepo<BaseModel>'.
            // Cannot implicitly convert type 'TestGeneric.NewRepo' to 'TestGeneric.BaseRepo<TestGeneric.BaseModel>'.
            // Cannot convert source type 'TestGeneric.NewRepo' to target type 'TestGeneric.BaseRepo<TestGeneric.BaseModel>'.
        }
    }
```

I just do not understand why t3 and t4 throwing does exceptions meanwhile t1 and t2 works. Even is NewModel is a subclass of BaseModel the last two does not works.

Comment: Check the duplicate - particularly my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573281/259769). I think it makes it easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to covariance feature of Generics:

As per Microsoft documentation about this tpoic:

> Covariance and contravariance are terms that refer to the ability to
>   use a more derived type (more specific) or a less derived type (less
>   specific) than originally specified. Generic type parameters support
>   covariance and contravariance to provide greater flexibility in
>   assigning and using generic types. When you are referring to a type
>   system, covariance, contravariance, and invariance have the following
>   definitions. The examples assume a base class named Base and a derived
>   class named Derived.
>
> Covariance
>
> Enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified.
>
> You can assign an instance of IEnumerable (IEnumerable(Of
>   Derived) in Visual Basic) to a variable of type IEnumerable.
>
> Contravariance
>
> Enables you to use a more generic (less derived) type than originally
>   specified.
>
> You can assign an instance of Action (Action(Of Base) in Visual
>   Basic) to a variable of type Action.
>
> Invariance
>
> Means that you can use only the type originally specified; so an
>   invariant generic type parameter is neither covariant nor
>   contravariant.
>
> You cannot assign an instance of List (List(Of Base) in Visual
>   Basic) to a variable of type List or vice versa.
>
> Covariant type parameters enable you to make assignments that look
>   much like ordinary Polymorphism, as shown in the following code.

```
C# 

IEnumerable<Derived> d = new List<Derived>(); IEnumerable<Base> b=d;
```

So, you can use interfaces, eg change your code to the following:

Create an `ICovariant` interface and use it instead of base class `BaseRepo`

```
public interface ICovariant<out T> where T : BaseModel
{

}
```

Then change your `BaseRepo` like below:

```
public class BaseRepo<T> : ICovariant<T> where T : BaseModel { }
```

Now you can be able to do this:

```
BaseRepo<BaseModel> t1 = new BaseRepo<BaseModel>();
BaseRepo<NewModel> t2 = new NewRepo();
ICovariant<BaseModel> t3 = new BaseRepo<NewModel>();
ICovariant<BaseModel> t4 = new NewRepo();
```

The hole code below:

```
public interface ICovariant<out T> where T : BaseModel
{

}

public abstract class BaseModel { }

public class NewModel : BaseModel { }

public class BaseRepo<T> : ICovariant<T> where T : BaseModel { }

class NewRepo : BaseRepo<NewModel> { }

class Test
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        BaseRepo<BaseModel> t1 = new BaseRepo<BaseModel>();
        BaseRepo<NewModel> t2 = new NewRepo();
        ICovariant<BaseModel> t3 = new BaseRepo<NewModel>();
        ICovariant<BaseModel> t4 = new NewRepo();
    }
}
```

[Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

[Variance in Generic Interfaces (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces)

Comment: Yes, I know. The VS showed me this option. But this works: ```BaseModel base = new NewModel()``` So I do not understand if I use it as generic why is it not working. That's my real question.

Comment: @DavidSzilagyi, i have updated my answer hope this help you out.

Comment: @DavidSzilagyi, does this help you out ? still have issues ? please accept a solution if an answer helped you so can other people benifit from it as well.

Comment: Yes. It is help just like the explanation of covariance. Thank you :)

Comment: Its a pleasure :)