# Cannot convert from Type<Type> to IType<IType>

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to implement a generic Excel Export.

I've created two Interfaces `IData` and `IDataList`. `IData` provides a function to get the Data transformed to an array and `IDataList` a function to get the corresponding names of the properties.

The interfaces

```
public interface IData
{
    string[] GetData();
}

public interface IDataList<IData> : IList<IData>
{
    string[] GetHeader();
}
```

The classes

```
public Data : IData
{
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string[] GetData()
    {
        return new [col1];
    }
}
public DataList : List<Data>, IDataList<Data>
{
    public string[] GetHeader()
    {
        return new ["col1"];
    }
}
```

Trying to use it

```
public void CreateDocument(IDataList<IData> dataList)
{
    // ...
    worksheet.Import(dataList.GetHeader(), RowIdx++, ColIdx, false);

    // ...
    foreach (IData data in dataList)
    {
        worksheet.Import(data.GetData(), RowIdx++, ColIdx, false);
    }
}

DataList data {get;set;} = new DataList();
// ... populate data

CreateDocument(data);
```

The project won't compile with the error message:
`Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DataList' to 'IDataList<IData>'`

I was wondering if you could point me in the right direction?

**Edit**: This question has been marked a duplicate of [Why an inherited interface can't be converted to its base interface in generic context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571409/c-sharp-why-an-inherited-interface-cant-be-converted-to-its-base-interface-in). While that question does explain why I can't call the function the way I've tried it does not help me resolve my issue.

I'm trying to implement the interfaces that I have designed in order to write a generic function `WriteDocument()`. This means that I require access to the functions `GetHeader()` and `GetData()`. Some people have suggested to use `IEnumerable` instead of `IList` but  I haven't been able to successfully implement that either.

What I have are multiple objects that all have to be written in the same style to an Excel file. The objects have different properties. With the help of `GetData()` I can convert these properties to a string array which can easily be dumped to the excel file. The `GetHeader()` function returns the names of these properties in the same order as `GetData()`.

I'm open to a different approach however I'm not sure where to get started. It would be cool to have the `WriteDocument()` function in a generic way so I don't have to duplicate the code for every object.

**Edit2**: Instead of trying to solve this with generics there's a much simpler solution. Rewrite CreateDocument—Function:

```
public void CreateDocument(string[] header, IEnumerable<string[]> data) { }
```

The classes and interface need a slight change

```
public interface IHasHeader { string[] GetHeader(); }
public class DataList : List<Data>, IHasHeader { }
public class Data : IData { }
```

The interfaces aren't actually *required* anymore at this point.

The function can then be used as follows:

```
public DataList data = new DataList();
// data.Add(new Data(){ ... })
CreateDocument(data.GetHeader(), data.Select(x => x.GetData()));
```

I don't have the required reputation to add a solution. If anyone were to convert it to a solution I'd be willing to accept.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on why you want to add a generic to `IDataList`? I appears that you don't use this generic type in the interface definition itself, making it redundant.

Comment: This is the most common mistake i see with generics `Type<Type>` is not `IType<IType>` they are different (even though it looks like it should work), the best you can hope for is a convenient  `IType` which will limit its usage. I think this problem needs to be rethought. Without a more concrete example its hard to know which way you should do this

Comment: Let's say I had a `List<Strawberry>`? Should I be able to cast it to a `List<IFruit>`? The answer is no - since then I'd be able to `Add` another fruit to it. That shows the general principle. `A<B>` can't be cast to `A<IB>`.

Comment: Sorry i had a spelling mistake. convenient = covarient

Comment: Polymorphism doesn't work the same when there are generics somewhere in inheritance hierarachy

Comment: @mjwills and chriz That actually makes a lot of sense and is the core error.

Comment: @TheGeneral What I'm trying to achieve is a function to which I can pass a List<T> where T may be any class. They all provide the function 'GetData()' to transform the object to a string array. Which can easily be written to the excel file.

Comment: @TomasSmagurauskas - Polymorphism doesn't change when there are generics in the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method to take any list by telling it it gets a `IEnumerable`, the base type of `List<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`. This is a non-generic type. If you'd take `IList<SomeType>` here, you'd need to specify the type explicitly.

See an example below how to use the IEnumerable in a method and check it:

```
private class MyClass { }
private class MyClassWithInterface : IMyClass { }
private interface IMyClass { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ITakeLists(new List<MyClass>()); // it is
    ITakeLists(new List<MyClassWithInterface>()); // isInstanceOf
    ITakeLists(new List<int>()); // it is not
    //ITakeLists(new MyClass()); // Error, is not derived from IEnumerable
}

private static void ITakeLists(IEnumerable myList)
{
    if (myList is List<MyClass>)
        Console.WriteLine("it is");
    else if(typeof(IMyClass).IsAssignableFrom(myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]))
        Console.WriteLine("isInstanceOf");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("it is not :(");
}
```

Comment: I'm okay with an Enumerable instead of a List. However I need the function ```GetHeader()```. So I've tried inheriting from an Enumerable: ```public interface IDataList<IData> : IEnumerable<IData>``` for the implementation I took a list ```public class DataList : List<Data>, IDataList<Data>```. The parameter type stays the same ```public void CreateDocument(IDataList<IData> data)
```. With the same Exception: Cannot convert from ```DataList``` to ```IDataList<IData>```.

Comment: The point is, you cannot inherit from any other type where the generic parameter is something else. `TypeA<InnerType>` can never be `TypeA<AnyOtherInnerType>`. Why dont you simply derive your `DataList`-class from another interface `IHasHeader`? Then, if you only need this method here, you can call it on that object via this interface `CreateDocument(IHasHeader list)`.